# css loader not working - webpack does not recognize css type file

Tags: webpack, loader

this is my **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = {
    mode: "development"
}
```

the **style.css** file

```
.hello {
    color: red
}
```

- I did install : npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader
  However, I get this parsing error. Not sure what it is

  Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

  > .hello {
  >   |     color: red
  >   | }

Comment: Everything seems to be ok, Are you sure that the error message is talking about that `style.css` file?

Comment: please post the complete error stack